# Decreasing of number of electrons in direction opposite to current

Tags: electricity

When a current is established in a wire,the free electrons drift in the direction opposite to the current.does the free electrons in the wire continuously decrease?

Answer (score 2):

No. If that were to happen, there would be a net positive charge in the wire which would oppose the current. What happens is that a constant stream of electrons is present, with the voltage source as the reservoir.